# Updating the position of a rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to get familiar with pygame so am starting with a simple program that draws a rectangle and moves it around with the mouse. The rectangle draws fine however it does not move with the mouse position and I cannot think why.

I found one other with this problem however this fix didnt work for me and was much more long winded than I felt it needed to be.

```py
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,300))

# --- mainloop / event loop ---
running = True
playerstartposX = 100
playerstartposY = 100
playerwidth = 50
playerheight = 50
screen.fill((30,30,30))
newrect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0) , ( playerstartposX ,
                                                 playerstartposY ,
                                                 playerwidth ,
                                                 playerheight))

pygame.display.update()

while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False

        elif event.type == 4: #if event is mouse motion
            newrect.move(event.pos) #move the rectangle to mouse pos

    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4` is not an event type. An event type is `MOUSEMOTION` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)).

Create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
newrect = pygame.Rect(playerstartposX, playerstartposY, playerwidth, playerheight)
```

Change its position when the event occurs:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION: 
    newrect.center = event.pos
```

In the main application loop you've to continuously

- handle the events
- clear the display
- draw the scene respectively rectangle
- update the display

If you want to control the frames per second, then you can pass a parameter to the method [`.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) rather than `pygame.time.delay`:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
playerstartposX = 100
playerstartposY = 100
playerwidth = 50
playerheight = 50
newrect = pygame.Rect(playerstartposX, playerstartposY, playerwidth, playerheight)

while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    # handle the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION: 
            newrect.center = event.pos

    # clear the display
    screen.fill((30,30,30))

    # draw the rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), newrect)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the event type you need to check against is `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` (I believe it's 1024?) and you are checking with 4.

Then you have to redraw the rect on every iteration of the main loop to reflect the updated position

Comment: When I printed the event.type. The output was always 4 when I moved my mouse. I originally used mousemotion however I changed it when trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: The value might change between versions, better to use the constant (I checked it with 2.0.0.dev4)